# Is a journal based on extending Wikipedia articles feasible?

Tags: publications, wikipedia

A large part of the work in writing a paper in my field (theoretical CS and economics) is writing the introduction, the problem description, the motivation, and the related work. A large part of this writeup repeats in different articles studying a similar problem; thus there is a waste of effort. I thought of initiating a journal in which the authors will be instructed to base this part of their papers on relevant Wikipedia pages. Each article would start with a paragraph such as the following:

> "This paper extends the Wikipedia article ABC (version from date of submission). Our contributions are as follows: (a) we prove that the ABC theorem is valid not only for $n=2$ but also for $n=3$. (b) We refute the ABC conjecture for $n=4$. (c) We present an efficient algorithm for solving the ABC problem for the case $n=2$.

The authors are responsible for ensuring that the Wikipedia article at the date of submission is uptodate, contains a complete problem statement, and all relevant related work.
The referees will have to verify this. Then, the rest of the paper will be verified as usual.
If the paper is published, then the new contributions will be added to the ABC page.

Advantages:

- The literature survey will be done only once, and it will be kept uptodate.
- The notation will be uniform (based on the Wikipedia article).

Current journals will probably not agree to this scheme. But can it work with a new journal? Is this scheme reasonable?

Comment: I don't think most of today's research is relevant for Wikipedia (today) and should be added there (imo against Wikipedia guidelines)

Comment: Would Wikipedia agree to this scheme?  Could you really have a journal (which will not be super-prestigious) where all the statements of the problems are notable enough to be mentioned in Wikipedia?

Comment: I think it would make more sense if the journal itself had its own wiki with the common contents on it. Wikipedia itself has its own policies, you can't enforce that the authors will take care of editing the Wikipedia pages to comply with your journal requirements if they don't have control over the wiki's contents (e.g., anyone can roll back their edits).

Comment: @Alexander Woo: I don't know about theoretical CS and economics, but in math it is not difficult to think of topics on which many papers have been written (sometimes even one or more books) that presently have NO details in any Wikipedia article, at least as far as I can determine. The very first thing I tried is an example --- [lineability in a vector space](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lineability%22+%22functions%22). The 4th topic I tried is another: [uniform rectifiability](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uniform+rectifiability%22) (only mentioned in a few mathematician's bios).

Comment: So what are you supposed to do if you do not like the Wikipedia page for that topic? For instance, because it uses a notation that you find ineffective, it contains statements you disagree with, or cites a lot of content that you do not consider relevant (and if such a journal becomes relevant, it seems likely that everyone and their cat will add shameless advertising to Wikipedia pages).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, see my post. re "*that you find ineffective*"; just use that "*ineffective*" notation or **edit it** to an effective one. re "*contains statements you disagree*"; if you disagree with the falsehoods on Wikipedia, kindly **edit it**, at a minimum, delete it. if you disagree with the truths on Wikipedia, welp, a fake news site is what does that, not a journal. re "*cites a lot of content that you do not consider relevant*". Same thing, edit over.

Comment: @Miguel, re "*policy*"; The policies are usually reasonable and thus **compatible**. re "*control*"; I think you meant anyone can rollback rollbacks and all logs are kept with all versions being individually referenceable.

Comment: @Pacerier You are assuming that different editors agree on what's effective and relevant here. That's a strong assumption, especially if you move into the specifics of people's research. People haven't agreed on a single preferred notation even for relatively basic concepts.

Comment: I am wondering about your initial premise for doing this. The intros to most academic papers do **not** go back to *a priori* things - it assumes readers are *au fait* with current developments and only tersely refers to them in the context of the author(s) research. Likewise the selected references vary from one paper/research angle to another. Even if the situation were as you say - wouldn't it be better to put these "standard intros" into Pedia page on the journal's own website rather than burden Wikipedia ?

Comment: @Trunk, this is likely a new topic, thus going back a few steps.. and you are at root. References vary but all come from the same set (common global). Instead of having a private wiki, putting it global merges all researchers. (A separate benefit is that it is an interesting use case / metaresearch; what Erel wanted?) ¶ re "*..burden..*"; That's a common myth and 180degree wrong perception (hence I take pains to write the contrary answer below). Wikipedia ***wants*** the content. Putting it there helps the global world instead of benefitting just the ivyed group, that's the whole point.

Comment: FedericoPoloni, re "*agree*"; you read wrongly. Having no preferred nothing is the common case (grep "costs" in clay shirky's article, in my post) and raison detre of Wikipedia. @FedericoPoloni

Comment: @Pacerier Ever added content to a Wiki page ? They break your ba11$ on every cussed "fact" lacking a citation, they frequently quash much of your edits as they consider - without ever considering if people of their background could be qualified to make such decisions - appropriate. Unpaid and unqualified editing leads to nasty edits. Not the way to go for academic research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are already three journals very similar to this idea:

- [WikiJournal of Medicine](http://www.wikijmed.org/)
- [WikiJournal of Science](http://www.wikijsci.org/)
- [WikiJournal of Humanities](http://www.wikijhum.org/)

There is even a [UserGroup](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/WikiJournal_User_Group) in which these are operated.

Comment: The links provided show this answer is wrong.  Why did people upvote this?

Comment: Because the Wikijournals are close enough to the OP's suggestion, while respecting Wikipedia's rules and using the same format as Wikipedia.

Comment: *very similar to this idea* -- not really

Comment: While it is not exactly what I had in mind, it is a very interesting step in that direction. The fact that it is open-access and uses the Wikipedia format makes it easy - both legally and technically - to copy & paste content to and from Wikipedia.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi I'm not so sure this format supports copy and pasting from Wikipedia articles... why is that so core to your idea?

Answer (score 6):

No, this will not work.  You claim

> A large part of this writeup repeats in different articles studying a similar problem; thus there is a waste of effort

but the effort wasted is actually not so big compared to the extra effort required to coordinate publishing with a wiki.

Furthermore, Wikipedia users will be editing the wiki with different goals in mind than the goals of your journal's authors.  Wikipedia is not meant for containing problem statements.

Answer (score -4):

**Yes, this will work.** (If you do it, you will see that this is true.)

Contrary to what the answer above wrote, it's  simple and not costly to make it work because anyone can edit Wikipedia. So whatever content you want to put on Wikipedia you are allowed to put it there. Generally, and by design. You are [in fact very welcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold) for **Wikipedia is meant to be edited by anyone** under any personal/selfish goals except those contrary to what is explicitly banned.

Also, notability is a completely gray concept in Wikipedia and is usually enforced this way: if you have budget for a   journal you **can expect** your budget to pass `WP:N`'s muster. (since the threshold has been found to be entirely subjective) One might guess that the enforcement follows the rules, but longtime users know it's the other way round. Just today I came across yet another article ("[Phrasal template](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Phrasal_template&oldid=179068568)") that is up (*notable*) and has been up for over 15 years.

One small disadvantage is that  someone will come alone and remove/edit your content (because anyone can edit). This is [by design] feature-not-bug as far as  Wikipedia is concerned; whether there are *trolls*  camping at your particular topic/subject is irrelevant.

It's a small con because typically **every single log is kept**. So all you have to do when there is a (slightest bit of) fork is to incorporate it (aka edit over) which is in fact what a wiki is all about, that is, collaboration with the world. I understand sometimes one simply does not have the time budget to bother incorporating foreign changes and deadlines are yesterday in which case you **can**  simply revert it to your wanted version with your new patch on that thus passing the buck to the other side to do "that incorporation work" from the new outstanding version, accepting that they might also be in the same situation which means that new outstanding version may also be reverted tomorrow unincorporated.

Note that one faux pas is to revert a fork while adding no new content (and without prevailing in talkpage discussion that can get incredibly lengthy; you don't have to prevail/bother with discussion btw if you have new content to add, and in fact there are many users/accounts who have a **policy of zero-discussion** (which you might find helpful, depending on your goals) which is completely accepted, and [Wikipedia is really huge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedians) when contrasted to SE and other forums where user types can be rounded up into 3 or 4 types at most and people/culture is only allowed to think either Left or Right, and contains probably  30 or 40 different cultures of users and more, of which only the [metapedian](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Metapedianism) is the most visible). Note that if you habitually do this you can actually get banned. But this is also not a con since you don't have to do that as **every single log is kept** so if your journal is *that* infrequent that between your edits there is already a fork trying to [survive](https://archive.is/HsiYf#selection-1039.29-1039.35), you can actually just ignore the fork simply by referencing specifically the version you want (thus from the default POV, it is you trying to survive; until your next  article update, which *will* come till your journal is dead)  and articles are  [never complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_a_work_in_progress)).

Finally, re "*If the paper is published, then the new contributions will be added [to the page]*"; Win-win !

Comment: What do you mean by "fork" here? As far as I understand there are no branches on Wikipiedia: the history is linear with only one most recent version at each time.

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Edit_warring ?

Comment: I didn't italize <fork> as I think it has a pretty standard meaning [pastebin.com/CJf8NHcW](https://pastebin.com/CJf8NHcW) ¶ In the page linked, ""use common sense, and do not participate in edit wars"" is what I meant and failing to do so can actually get you banned. as I've already mentioned.